# How to check if a specifc record exists excluding other records?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve a record  which I can do for both firstName and lastName but when I try to retrieve either firstName or lastName the problem I'm having is that if a record has a space for firstName  or lastName it  also brings up  those records which it shouldn't. Please see image attachement.[records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dT7rx.png) It should only display theo audas record and not the rest.

```
$sql = ("SELECT personnel.firstName, personnel.lastName FROM personnel WHERE (firstName = ? AND lastName= ? ) OR (firstName = ?) OR (lastName = ?)");
$stmt= $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $_REQUEST['firstName'],$_REQUEST['lastName'], $_REQUEST['firstName'], $_REQUEST['lastName']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$data = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       array_push($data, $row);
    }
 echo json_encode($data);
}
```

I'm fairly new to MySQL and would like to know what I'm doing wrong please.

Comment: What's the exact data type of the columns `firstName` and `lastName`?

Comment: The data types for the columns are string.

Comment: "string" is not a valid data type in MySQL. See [MySQL Data Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-types.html).

Comment: I'm guessing you are sending an empty string either for `firstName` or `lastName`  thus matching your OR condition. Can you show the request you are sending?

Comment: Char is the data type.

Comment: I've shown the request. Please see attachment records in the question.

Comment: `$_REQUEST['LastName']` is an empty string. So all the rows where `lastName = ''` are returned because of `OR (lastName = ?)`

Comment: Why do you allow empty `lastName` in the table in the first place?

Comment: When `$_REQUEST['lastName']` is empty you probably don't want to use `lastName = ?` in the query.

Comment: added tag [tag:php], because all those PHP ("wannabe") _programmers_ can learn from this to write better SQL 

Answer (score 1):

Change the query so it only matches a name if the corresponding input was not empty.

```
$sql = ("
    SELECT personnel.firstName, personnel.lastName 
    FROM personnel 
    WHERE ((? != '' AND ? != '' AND firstName = ? AND lastName= ? ) 
        OR (? != '' AND firstName = ?) 
        OR (? != '' lastName = ?)");
$stmt= $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", 
    $_REQUEST['firstName'], $_REQUEST['lastName'], $_REQUEST['firstName'], $_REQUEST['lastName'], 
    $_REQUEST['firstName'], $_REQUEST['firstName'], 
    $_REQUEST['lastName'], $_REQUEST['lastName']);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't understand this `? != ''` and how it is relates to firstName because I thought it needed an actual column name.

Comment: `?` gets replaced with the value of the variable. You can compare that with a column or an expression.

Comment: Why do you think you need an actual column name? You can write `WHERE 1 = 1` with no column names.

Comment: Hi Barmar, the query doesn't work for when a firstName and lastName both have different values. It displays the record with the correct firstName along with incorrect surname, e.g. firstName is theo and lastName is audas but when I enter theo and then with a different surname it displays the surname. Any ideas as to why.

Comment: Your original query does the same thing. `OR (firstName = ?)` makes the condition true whenever the firstName matches, regardless of the entered lastName.